# Can blood potency increase while a kindred is in torpor?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

Blood potency increases over time as a Kindred gets older, that much is clear - but does the kindred have to be “active” for their blood to thicken, or will it continue to do so even if they’re in torpor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, a vampire must be active for his or her Blood Potency to rise. In fact, according to the description on page 215 of the **Vampire: the Masquerade 5th Edition** core rulebook, Blood Potency slowly drops while a vampire is in torpor.

Comment: It's worth noting that Blood Potency will decrease 1 dot for every 50 years spent in Torpor. It will never drop below the requirement for their generation though.